# Continuity of infimum with respect to argument of predicate

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

I am interested in an expression of the form $$x^*=\inf\{\,x\in X:P(x,y)>0\,\}$$
where $P$ is continuous in both $x$ and $y$. With this equation, it would seem that every $y$ is mapped to a value $x^*$ such that I can define a function $x^*(\,y\,).$ Is it generally true, or are there any sufficient conditions, that would allow me to conclude that $x^*$ as "defined" above is continuous in $y$?

I have to admit that I am not quite sure how to think about this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not true in general: $\{(x,y) : P(x,y)>0\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but we could construct $P$ so that this set includes the union of two open non-intersecting discs and one partially "hides" the other when looking at leftmost limit points in the graph, causing a jump in the $x^*$ function. This might help think about some sufficient conditions...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. When you say "partially hide", in the sense of looking at the leftmost limit point, would that issue be remedied when considering a closed set $\{(x,y):P(x,y)\geq0\}$ with $x^*=\inf\{x\in X:P(x,y)\geq0\}$?

Comment: No: I'm thinking of something like $P(x,y) = -(1-x^2-y^2)(1-(x-2)^2-(y-1)^2)$. $P$ is zero on the two circles $x^2+y^2=1$ and $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2 = 1$; positive inside either circle; and negative outside the two circles. No matter what you do with the $P=0$ case, you'll have $-1 \leq x^* \leq 0$ when $-1 < y < 1$, but $1 \leq x^* \leq 2$ when $1 < y < 2$.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I just plotted the graphs. Everything's clear now.